# How to extend delay for slide toggle without repeating effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, slidetoggle

I want to make it so that when a button is clicked a hidden div is displayed for a few seconds and hidden again. This code accomplishes that:

HTML:

```
<button class="clicky">click me</button>

<div class="flashy" style="display: none; width: 150px; font-size: 18px; margin-top: 25px;">
    Now you see me!
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(".clicky").on("click", function() {
    flashDiv();
});

function flashDiv()
{
    $(".flashy").slideToggle(100).effect("highlight", 300).delay(4000).slideToggle(100);
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/NRz34/1/

However, there's one thing that I really don't like about it: if you click the button multiple times in quick succession, the effect will repeat over and over again (i.e. it will slide down, display for a few seconds, slide up, then repeat however many times you clicked the button).

My question is, how can this be modified so that instead of sliding up and down over and over again (for however many times it was clicked), it just stays down for 4 seconds after the last click?

**Example:**

Current behavior when clicked multiple times:

1. click click click
2. slides down
3. displays for 4 seconds
4. slides up
5. repeats two more times

Desired behavior when clicked multiple times:

1. click click click
2. slides down
3. displays for 4 seconds
4. slides up

**Note:**

I realize that I could check if the DIV is visible and ignore the button press if it is, but this isn't quite the behavior I'm wanting. You see, I want the DIV to stay visible for 4 seconds *after* the last button press, so if the button is pressed and then is pressed again 2 seconds later, the button should stay visible for 4 more seconds (for a total display time of 6 seconds).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `.stop(true)` to the beginning of your call.  This will stop any current animation and clear out the animation queue, and start again.  Also, use `slideDown`/`slideUp` so you don't end up in an undetermined state.  If you click when it is already shown, `slideDown()` won't do anything, and then 4000ms will be added from that time until the `slideUp()`.

```
function flashDiv()
{
    $(".flashy").stop(true).slideDown(100).effect("highlight", 300).delay(4000).slideUp(100);
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/efeZZ/)

**EDIT**:  I have learned that `.delay()` and `.stop()` do not play nice together, as referenced in the doumentation (http://api.jquery.com/delay/).

To get around this, you can use `.animate()` with a useless animation, such as animating the `width` to the current `width` value.  Also, stopping the animation can cause the `highlight` effect to get stuck, so I clear the `background-color` at the beginning of the call:

```
function flashDiv()
{
    $(".flashy").css('background-color', 'transparent').stop(true).slideDown(100).effect('highlight', 300).animate({'width':150}, 4000).slideUp(100);
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/efeZZ/)

Comment: Very slick, but it seems kind of glitchy. Try clicking it at 1 or 2 second intervals and after a few clicks it slides back up.

Comment: Solved, see edit.  There might be a better way, but this seems to work. (Edit: whoops... forgot to add stop back... works now)

Comment: Very nice! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Revised solution that allows flashy to stay open after each additional clcik

```
jQuery(".clicky").on("click", flashDiv);

function flashDiv() {

    var $flash = $(".flashy"), timer=$flash.data('timer');
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        setSlideUp($flash);
    } else {
        $flash.slideDown(100).effect("highlight", 300, function () {
            setSlideUp($flash);
        })
    } 
}

function setSlideUp($flash) {
    var delay = 2000; /* shorter for demo purposes*/
    var timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $flash.slideUp();
       $flash.data('timer', false)
    }, delay)
    $flash.data('timer', timer)
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C38qh/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: So this will prevent the effect from happening multiple times, but it won't extend the time the DIV is shown if the button is clicked again, right?

Comment: prevent yes... not sure what you mean about extending time. That won't happen either

Comment: ok...just reread about leaving open longer. Will need to completely reconfigure this for that behavior

Comment: revised my solution to include extending time open

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setTimeout()` to be able to cancel the `delay`, as jQuery's delay can't be cancelled.

```
var timer;
jQuery(".clicky").on("click", function() {
    flashDiv();
});

function flashDiv()
{
    if($(".flashy").is(":visible")){
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
        $(".flashy").stop(true);
        timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
            $(".flashy").slideUp(100);
        }, 4000);
    }
    else{
        $(".flashy").slideDown(100).effect("highlight", 300);
        timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
            $(".flashy").slideUp(100);
        }, 4000);
    } 

}
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/g2wV4/3)

This way, you start a timer to do the `slideUp` after 4 seconds, but if there is another click and the *flashy* is visible, you stop the previous timer and start a new one.